# PopUnder is triggering even if cookie is set

Tags: javascript, cookies, popup

I'm working on an existing popunder script and it works great but the problem is that it triggers even if the `cookie` is set, its not supposed to trigger if the cookie is set and I can't figure it out how to solve this, I want it to trigger once every 1 hour, thanks

```
/**
 * Smart Popunder maker.
 * This class provides an easy way to make a popunder.
 * Avoid blocked on Google Chrome
 *
 * Note: For Google Chrome, to avoid blocked so each popunder will be  fired by each click.
 *
 * @author: Phan Thanh Cong aka chiplove <ptcong90@gmail.com>
 * @license: MIT
 *
 * Edit by: Rafel Sansó <rafel.sanso@gmail.com>
 * 
 * Changelog
 *
 * version 2.3.2.1; Apr 23, 2015
 * - Eventually, the popup doesn't launch. To prevent this I comment lines 174, 180 and 208
 * 
 */
(function(window){
    "use strict";

    var Popunder = function(url, options){ this.__construct(url, options); },
    counter = 0,
    lastPopTime = 0,
    alertCalled = false,
    baseName = 'ChipPopunder',
    parent = top != self ? top : self,
    userAgent = navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase(),
    browser = {
        webkit: /webkit/.test(userAgent),
        mozilla: /mozilla/.test(userAgent) && !/(compatible|webkit)/.test(userAgent),
        chrome: /chrome/.test(userAgent),
        msie: /msie|trident\//.test(userAgent) && !/opera/.test(userAgent),
        firefox: /firefox/.test(userAgent),
        safari: /safari/.test(userAgent) && !/chrome/.test(userAgent),
        opera: /opera/.test(userAgent),
        version: parseInt(userAgent.match(/(?:[^\s]+(?:ri|ox|me|ra)\/|trident\/.*?rv:)([\d]+)/i)[1], 10)
    },
    helper = {
        simulateClick: function(url) {
            var a = document.createElement("a"),
                nothing = "",
                evt = document.createEvent("MouseEvents");
            a.href = url || "data:text/html,<script>window.close();<\/script>;";
            document.body.appendChild(a);
            evt.initMouseEvent("click", true, true, window, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, true, false, false, true, 0, null);
            a.dispatchEvent(evt);
            a.parentNode.removeChild(a);
        },
        blur:  function(popunder) {
            try {
                popunder.blur();
                popunder.opener.window.focus();
                window.self.window.focus();
                window.focus();
                if (browser.firefox) {
                    this.openCloseWindow(popunder);
                } else if (browser.webkit) {
                    // try to blur popunder window on chrome
                    // but not works on chrome 41
                    // so we should wrap this to avoid chrome display warning
                    if (!browser.chrome || (browser.chrome && browser.version < 41)) {
                        this.openCloseTab();
                    }
                } else if (browser.msie) {
                    setTimeout(function() {
                        popunder.blur();
                        popunder.opener.window.focus();
                        window.self.window.focus();
                        window.focus();
                    }, 1000);
                }
            } catch(err) {}
        },
        openCloseWindow: function(popunder) {
            var tmp = popunder.window.open("about:blank");
            tmp.focus();
            tmp.close();
            setTimeout(function() {
                try {
                    tmp = popunder.window.open("about:blank");
                    tmp.focus();
                    tmp.close();
                } catch (e) {}
            }, 1);
        },
        openCloseTab: function() {
            this.simulateClick();
        },
        detachEvent: function(event, callback, object) {
            var object = object || window;
            if (!object.removeEventListener) {
                return object.detachEvent("on" + event, callback);
            }
            return object.removeEventListener(event, callback);
        },
        attachEvent: function(event, callback, object) {
            var object = object || window;
            if (!object.addEventListener) {
                return object.attachEvent("on" + event, callback);
            }
            return object.addEventListener(event, callback);
        },
        mergeObject: function() {
            var obj = {}, i, k;
            for(i = 0; i < arguments.length; i++) {
                for (k in arguments[i]) {
                    obj[k] = arguments[i][k];
                }
            }
            return obj;
        },
        getCookie: function(name) {
            var cookieMatch = document.cookie.match(new RegExp(name+"=[^;]+", "i"));
            return cookieMatch ? decodeURIComponent(cookieMatch[0].split("=")[1]) : null;
        },
        setCookie: function(name, value, expires, path) {
            // expires must be number of minutes or instance of Date;
            if(expires === null || typeof expires == 'undefined') {
                expires = '';
            } else {
                var date;
                if (typeof expires == 'number') {
                    date = new Date();
                    date.setTime(date.getTime() + expires * 60 * 1e3);
                } else {
                    date = expires;
                }
                expires = "; expires=" + date.toUTCString();
            }
            document.cookie = name + "=" + escape(value) + expires + "; path=" + (path || '/');
        }
    };

    Popunder.prototype = {
        defaultWindowOptions: {
            width      : window.screen.width,
            height     : window.screen.height,
            left       : 0,
            top        : 0,
            location   : 1,
            toolbar    : 1,
            status     : 1,
            menubar    : 1,
            scrollbars : 1,
            resizable  : 1
        },
        defaultPopOptions: {
            cookieExpires : 60, // in minutes
            cookiePath    : '/',
            newTab        : true,
            blur          : true,
            blurByAlert   : false, //
            chromeDelay   : 500,
            smart         : false, // for feature, if browsers block event click to window/body
            beforeOpen    : function(){},
            afterOpen     : function(){}
        },
        // Must use the options to create a new window in chrome
        __chromeNewWindowOptions: {
            scrollbars : 0
        },
        __construct: function(url, options) {
            this.url      = url;
            this.index    = counter++;
            this.name     = baseName + '_' + (this.index);
            this.executed = false;

            this.setOptions(options);
            this.register();
        },
        register: function() {
            //if (this.isExecuted()) return;
            var self = this, w, i,
            elements = [],
            eventName = 'click',
            run = function(e) {
                // e.preventDefault();
                //if (self.shouldExecute()) {
                    lastPopTime = new Date().getTime();
                    self.setExecuted();
                    self.options.beforeOpen.call(undefined, this);
                    if (self.options.newTab) {
                        if (browser.chrome && browser.version > 30 && self.options.blur) {
                            window.open('javascript:window.focus()', '_self', '');
                            helper.simulateClick(self.url);
                            w = null;
                        } else {
                            w = parent.window.open(self.url, '_blank');
                            setTimeout(function(){
                                if (!alertCalled && self.options.blurByAlert) {
                                    alertCalled = true;
                                    alert();
                                }
                            }, 3);
                        }
                    } else {
                        w = parent.window.open(self.url, this.url, self.getParams());
                    }
                    if (self.options.blur) {
                        helper.blur(w);
                    }
                    self.options.afterOpen.call(undefined, this);
                    for(i in elements) {
                        helper.detachEvent(eventName, run, elements[i]);
                    }
                //}
            },
            inject = function(e){
                if (self.isExecuted()) {
                    helper.detachEvent('mousemove', inject);
                    return;
                }
                try {
                    if (e.originalTarget && typeof e.originalTarget[self.name] == 'undefined') {
                        e.originalTarget[self.name] = true;
                        helper.attachEvent(eventName, run, e.originalTarget);
                        elements.push(e.originalTarget);
                    }
                } catch(err) {}
            };

            // smart injection
            if (this.options.smart) {
                helper.attachEvent('mousemove', inject);
            } else {
                helper.attachEvent(eventName, run, window);
                elements.push(window);

                helper.attachEvent(eventName, run, document);
                elements.push(document);
            }
        },
        shouldExecute: function() {
            if (browser.chrome && lastPopTime && lastPopTime + this.options.chromeDelay > new Date().getTime()) {
                return false;
            }
            return !this.isExecuted();
        },
        isExecuted: function() {
            return this.executed || !!helper.getCookie(this.name);
        },
        setExecuted: function() {
            this.executed = true;
            helper.setCookie(this.name, 1, this.options.cookieExpires, this.options.cookiePath);
        },
        setOptions: function(options) {
            this.options = helper.mergeObject(this.defaultWindowOptions, this.defaultPopOptions, options || {});
            if (!this.options.newTab && browser.chrome) {
                for(var k in this.__chromeNewWindowOptions) {
                    this.options[k] = this.__chromeNewWindowOptions[k];
                }
            }
        },
        getParams: function() {
            var params = '', k;
            for (k in this.options) {
                if (typeof this.defaultWindowOptions[k] != 'undefined') {
                    params += (params ? "," : "") + k + "=" + this.options[k];
                }
            }
            return params;
        }
    };
    Popunder.make = function(url, options) {
        return new this(url, options);
    };

    window.SmartPopunder = Popunder;

})(window);
```

I've tried in different ways to solve this but it won't work, what I need to mention is that, I'm a noob in javascript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

THANKS FOR NO HELP; I miss the old times when users went here for help even if they were a noob, they would still get some help, nowadays all you get is "Suggested Editing" they fix you and "I" and nothing much, what if English is not my first language? FFS what happened to this community?

Anyways, maybe there will be noob people like me that will want to use this popunder, i fixed the problem here is the full working code.

```
/**
 * Smart Popunder maker.
 * This class provides an easy way to make a popunder.
 * Avoid blocked on Google Chrome
 *
 * Note: For Google Chrome, to avoid blocked so each popunder will be  fired by each click.
 *
 * @author: Phan Thanh Cong aka chiplove <ptcong90@gmail.com>
 * @license: MIT
 *
 * Edit by: Rafel Sansó <rafel.sanso@gmail.com>
 * 
 * Changelog
 *
 * version 2.3.2.1; Apr 23, 2015
 * - Eventually, the popup doesn't launch. To prevent this I comment lines 174, 180 and 208
 * 
 */
(function(window){
    "use strict";

    var Popunder = function(url, options){ this.__construct(url, options); },
    counter = 0,
    lastPopTime = 0,
    alertCalled = false,
    baseName = 'ChipPopunder',
    parent = top != self ? top : self,
    userAgent = navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase(),
    browser = {
        webkit: /webkit/.test(userAgent),
        mozilla: /mozilla/.test(userAgent) && !/(compatible|webkit)/.test(userAgent),
        chrome: /chrome/.test(userAgent),
        msie: /msie|trident\//.test(userAgent) && !/opera/.test(userAgent),
        firefox: /firefox/.test(userAgent),
        safari: /safari/.test(userAgent) && !/chrome/.test(userAgent),
        opera: /opera/.test(userAgent),
        version: parseInt(userAgent.match(/(?:[^\s]+(?:ri|ox|me|ra)\/|trident\/.*?rv:)([\d]+)/i)[1], 10)
    },
    helper = {
        simulateClick: function(url) {
            var a = document.createElement("a"),
                nothing = "",
                evt = document.createEvent("MouseEvents");
            a.href = url || "data:text/html,<script>window.close();<\/script>;";
            document.body.appendChild(a);
            evt.initMouseEvent("click", true, true, window, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, true, false, false, true, 0, null);
            a.dispatchEvent(evt);
            a.parentNode.removeChild(a);
        },
        blur:  function(popunder) {
            try {
                popunder.blur();
                popunder.opener.window.focus();
                window.self.window.focus();
                window.focus();
                if (browser.firefox) {
                    this.openCloseWindow(popunder);
                } else if (browser.webkit) {
                    // try to blur popunder window on chrome
                    // but not works on chrome 41
                    // so we should wrap this to avoid chrome display warning
                    if (!browser.chrome || (browser.chrome && browser.version < 41)) {
                        this.openCloseTab();
                    }
                } else if (browser.msie) {
                    setTimeout(function() {
                        popunder.blur();
                        popunder.opener.window.focus();
                        window.self.window.focus();
                        window.focus();
                    }, 1000);
                }
            } catch(err) {}
        },
        openCloseWindow: function(popunder) {
            var tmp = popunder.window.open("about:blank");
            tmp.focus();
            tmp.close();
            setTimeout(function() {
                try {
                    tmp = popunder.window.open("about:blank");
                    tmp.focus();
                    tmp.close();
                } catch (e) {}
            }, 1);
        },
        openCloseTab: function() {
            this.simulateClick();
        },
        detachEvent: function(event, callback, object) {
            var object = object || window;
            if (!object.removeEventListener) {
                return object.detachEvent("on" + event, callback);
            }
            return object.removeEventListener(event, callback);
        },
        attachEvent: function(event, callback, object) {
            var object = object || window;
            if (!object.addEventListener) {
                return object.attachEvent("on" + event, callback);
            }
            return object.addEventListener(event, callback);
        },
        mergeObject: function() {
            var obj = {}, i, k;
            for(i = 0; i < arguments.length; i++) {
                for (k in arguments[i]) {
                    obj[k] = arguments[i][k];
                }
            }
            return obj;
        },
        getCookie: function(name) {
            var cookieMatch = document.cookie.match(new RegExp(name+"=[^;]+", "i"));
            return cookieMatch ? decodeURIComponent(cookieMatch[0].split("=")[1]) : null;
        },
        setCookie: function(name, value, expires, path) {
            // expires must be number of minutes or instance of Date;
            if(expires === null || typeof expires == 'undefined') {
                expires = '';
            } else {
                var date;
                if (typeof expires == 'number') {
                    date = new Date();
                    date.setTime(date.getTime() + expires * 60 * 1e3);
                } else {
                    date = expires;
                }
                expires = "; expires=" + date.toUTCString();
            }
            document.cookie = name + "=" + escape(value) + expires + "; path=" + (path || '/');
        }
    };

    Popunder.prototype = {
        defaultWindowOptions: {
            width      : window.screen.width,
            height     : window.screen.height,
            left       : 0,
            top        : 0,
            location   : 1,
            toolbar    : 1,
            status     : 1,
            menubar    : 1,
            scrollbars : 1,
            resizable  : 1
        },
        defaultPopOptions: {
            cookieExpires : 60, // in minutes
            cookiePath    : '/',
            newTab        : true,
            blur          : true,
            blurByAlert   : false, //
            chromeDelay   : 500,
            smart         : false, // for feature, if browsers block event click to window/body
            beforeOpen    : function(){},
            afterOpen     : function(){}
        },
        // Must use the options to create a new window in chrome
        __chromeNewWindowOptions: {
            scrollbars : 0
        },
        __construct: function(url, options) {
            this.url      = url;
            this.index    = counter++;
            this.name     = baseName + '_' + (this.index);
            this.executed = false;

            this.setOptions(options);
            this.register();
        },
        register: function() {
            if (this.isExecuted()) return;
            var self = this, w, i,
            elements = [],
            eventName = 'click',
            run = function(e) {
                // e.preventDefault();
                //if (self.shouldExecute()) {
                    lastPopTime = new Date().getTime();
                    self.setExecuted();
                    self.options.beforeOpen.call(undefined, this);
                    if (self.options.newTab) {
                        if (browser.chrome && browser.version > 30 && self.options.blur) {
                            window.open('javascript:window.focus()', '_self', '');
                            helper.simulateClick(self.url);
                            w = null;
                        } else {
                            w = parent.window.open(self.url, '_blank');
                            setTimeout(function(){
                                if (!alertCalled && self.options.blurByAlert) {
                                    alertCalled = true;
                                    alert();
                                }
                            }, 3);
                        }
                    } else {
                        w = parent.window.open(self.url, this.url, self.getParams());
                    }
                    if (self.options.blur) {
                        helper.blur(w);
                    }
                    self.options.afterOpen.call(undefined, this);
                    for(i in elements) {
                        helper.detachEvent(eventName, run, elements[i]);
                    }
                //}
            },
            inject = function(e){
                if (self.isExecuted()) {
                    helper.detachEvent('mousemove', inject);
                    return;
                }
                try {
                    if (e.originalTarget && typeof e.originalTarget[self.name] == 'undefined') {
                        e.originalTarget[self.name] = true;
                        helper.attachEvent(eventName, run, e.originalTarget);
                        elements.push(e.originalTarget);
                    }
                } catch(err) {}
            };

            // smart injection
            if (this.options.smart) {
                helper.attachEvent('mousemove', inject);
            } else {
                helper.attachEvent(eventName, run, window);
                elements.push(window);

                helper.attachEvent(eventName, run, document);
                elements.push(document);
            }
        },
        shouldExecute: function() {
            if (browser.chrome && lastPopTime && lastPopTime + this.options.chromeDelay > new Date().getTime()) {
                return false;
            }
            return !this.isExecuted();
        },
        isExecuted: function() {
            return this.executed || !!helper.getCookie(this.name);
        },
        setExecuted: function() {
            this.executed = true;
            helper.setCookie(this.name, 1, this.options.cookieExpires, this.options.cookiePath);
        },
        setOptions: function(options) {
            this.options = helper.mergeObject(this.defaultWindowOptions, this.defaultPopOptions, options || {});
            if (!this.options.newTab && browser.chrome) {
                for(var k in this.__chromeNewWindowOptions) {
                    this.options[k] = this.__chromeNewWindowOptions[k];
                }
            }
        },
        getParams: function() {
            var params = '', k;
            for (k in this.options) {
                if (typeof this.defaultWindowOptions[k] != 'undefined') {
                    params += (params ? "," : "") + k + "=" + this.options[k];
                }
            }
            return params;
        }
    };
    Popunder.make = function(url, options) {
        return new this(url, options);
    };

    window.SmartPopunder = Popunder;

})(window);
```

add the code above into a js file like popunder.js and in order to trigger it you will need to use this code

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.website.com/js/popunder.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
// use cookie expires on 1 hour * cookieExpires
SmartPopunder.make('https://www.website.com', {cookieExpires:60, newTab: true, width: window.screen.width, height: window.screen.height});
</script>
```

Regards